# node js sequelize Getting child and subchild in one association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have categories table that has many products and that products table has many images

I am able to get them separately but i want them together in one go

```
 const categoriesList = await Categories.findAll({
        include:['myProducts']
           
    })
```

and my relations are as follows

```
db.Products.hasMany(db.ProductImages,{as:"productImages",foreignKey: 'productId' })
db.Categories.hasMany(db.Products,{as:"myProducts",foreignKey:"categoryId"})
```

In what way i am able to get products with its images when I query for categories?

I Have tried with raw query

```
const resd=await db.sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM categories INNER JOIN products ON products.category=categories.id INNER JOIN productimages ON productimages.productId=products.id");
  res.json({re:resd})
```

It works fine but it obviously display all things together

I want them in a nested pattern

Expected behavior:

```
{
"id": 1164,
"name": "Shirt",
"color": "red",
"myProducts":[{
"id":1,
"name": "raglan",
"price":"1200",
categoryId:1164,
"productImages":[{
id:12,
"image":"someimage.png",
"productId":1
}]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `include` option inside the first `include` option:

```js
 const categoriesList = await Categories.findAll({
        include:[{
          model: Products,
          as: 'myProducts',
          include: [{
            model: ProductImages,
            as: 'productImages'
          }]
        }]
    })
```

Though I don't recommend to load all-in-one considering a lot of images being loaded.

Comment: Amm yeah but the thing is We have a limit for images per product so that shouldn't be an issue let me try your answer.